# PnP Framework, Client Context Hangs

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have been working on this for hours now and can't figure out even how to diagnose this issue.   When I run this code and step through it,  I get an AuthenticationManager class initated but when it goes to create the client context,  It just hangs.  No error, No break, No exception. Sits there and idles forever.

Thanks for the help,  this has been driving me crazy for way to long.

Here is my code (Personal Information has been changed obviously)

```
public static class SharepointAPI
{
    private static ClientContext cc { get; set; }

    private static void GenVar()
    {
        if(cc == null)
        {
            string appId = "a9f346f5-7229-4127-bfa2-7605c4593ca6";
            var scopes = new string[] { "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/.default" };
            string siteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/HR/";
            string tenant = "contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
            string certpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\cert.pfx";
            string certpass = @"Password123";
            var certificate509 = GetCertificate(certpath, certpass);
            cc = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager(clientId: appId, certificate: certificate509, tenantId: tenant)
                .GetContext(siteURL);

        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }    
    }
    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string filename, string pwd)
    {
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(filename, pwd);
        return certificate;
    }
```

Comment: Anybody have any ideas

Comment: I'll be keeping an eye on this, as I've just came across the same issue in a WPF app I've actually upgraded from OfficeDevPnPCore _to_ PnP.Framework. Done a tonne of refactoring and this little bit is stopping me from seeing how successful the refactor was :D

Answer (score 1):

This is t really an answer but I ended up going back to framework instead of core and used the old PnP.DEV and have had great success.  No issues.  So that is actually quite a bummer because I really wanted to italics core but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your scenario, but for me I had to use `GetContextAsync()`.

This was in WPF, and it was when a method was called off the back of an update to a DependencyProperty.

Therefore, the utility method I had built had to be async so I could await the call to `GetContextAsync()`, but I guess beyond that point you could just use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the call to the utility to make it synchronous if I needed to.

Comment: Using the async methods solved the problem for me too.